Problem with AVFoundation on iPhone 16 Pro Max
When compressing video recorded on the iPhone 16 Pro Max using AVFoundation, an issue occurs during audio compression. When calling AVAssetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer, the writer’s status changes to failed and outputs the following error message.
Some key codes:
self.audioSettings = @{
  AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
  AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @2,
  AVSampleRateKey: @44100,
  AVEncoderBitRateKey: @128000,
};

[self.audioInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:self.inputQueue usingBlock:^ {
  while (input.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [output copyNextSampleBuffer];
    if (sampleBuffer) {
        if ([input appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer]) {
          // Something went wrong here！
        }
    }
  }
}];

Error Info:
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "This operation cannot be completed" UserInfo={
  NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred（-12780）, 
  NSLocalizedDescription=This operation cannot be completed, 
  NSUnderlyingError=0x3023db8a0 {
    Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 "(null)"
  }
}

What happened and how do I fix it?
